# Spell checker for .NET / C#

Tags: c#, .net, spell-checking

Does somebody know a good multilanguage spell checker for C# - .NET?

I mean, I have [googled](http://www.google.es/#hl=es&sa=X&ei=agBxTYKYKsaYhQfr68E_&ved=0CBoQBSgA&q=spell+checker+C%23&spell=1&fp=30ac618ed16d8cea) it and I found some alternatives, but does someone have a good success story with one?

I need to add a spell checker to my application. I would like a library that integrates with `System.Windows.Forms.TexBox`, for example.

Also, my application is portable to Linux, Mac, (`using Mono`), so it should be 100% managed code.

---

**EDIT:** I'm looking for something that underlines with a red line a wrong word in the textbox and also proposes corrections in a contextmenu:
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't the native OS contain most spellchecking abilities for users entering text? Or do you spellchecking for code you are writing (like in comments, strings, etc.) If you are speaking of the latter, Visual Studio offers this built in, you just have to turn it on.

Comment: @slandau: It is for my application, see my edits.

Comment: I have used NetSpell. A project on codeproject. Works really well for my applications. Check the link that I have provided in my answer below.

Comment: you can still use the NetSpell library... But you need to modify it so that the it displays the suggestions in the context menu instead of the textbox on a new form.. A bit of modifications required .... or else you can buy UltimateSpell at http://www.karamasoft.com/ultimatespell/features.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't object to paying for it, ComponentOne has a [spellchecker](http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/SpellCheckerWinForms/) component which attaches to a normal Textbox, and provides the highlight and context menu.

I use it at my work, and have had no problems with it so far.

Answer (score 10):

There is a project called NetSpell. Link:
 http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/netspell.aspx

I have used it in my .Net winform application and it works like a charm. Let me know if you need anymore details and I can help you out. :)

Comment: I also need dictionary for spanish, do you know if it's easy to get?

Comment: the dictionary above is based on a group of text files. It already includes spanish my friend. and 6 other languages if I am not wrong :) all the best

Comment: Is NetSpell able to underline the word in the textbox? I did not see this functionality.

Comment: @Daniel It pop ups a window which displays the mispelled word in red and the suggestions to that word. it doesnot however underline the mispelled word in red.

Answer (score 0):

WPF has a built-in [SpellCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.isenabled.aspx); however, I don't believe its fully portable to Mono since its WPF and not WinForms.