# Replacing MS Word with a .net control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ms-word

We are doing some document publishing work and the users need the document to be opened in `MS Word` so that they can do 1) spell check and 2) grammar check, then they close the word document and we read the data from the word document and send it to database.

Opening and closing word document is creating some issues in our UI stability. We are planning to use a text control in the UI and the user can type text in the UI but we want the spell check and grammer check functionality in it. This will improve the stability of the application as there is no need to worry about the external msword app.

Comment: You can look into this post for spell checkers in net: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195460/spell-checker-for-net-c-sharp

Comment: What sort of UI? Winforms? WebForms? WPF?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SpellCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck.aspx)

> Provides real-time spell-checking functionality to text-editing
>   controls, such as TextBox and RichTextBox.

Answer (score 1):

We have been using [TX Text Control](http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/) for years for this purpose. It can import and export Word documents and it has a built in spell checker.